# Downloading a file around 8 to 12 mb in background Windows 8 metrostyle app Javascript

Tags: windows-8

I am new to Windows 8 developmet.
What I want to do is just a simple download in background the constraint is download should not stopped if app is killed or it is not in suspended or the running condition.
Any link where I can study and go forward highly appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two key resources that should answer most of your questions (and give you some source code to boot):

[Background Transfer Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61)

[Introduction to Background tasks (Word doc)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411)